# Woocommerce Grouped Products with Individual “Add To Cart” Button

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, product

I am trying to achieve the following:

On the grouped product detail page a Add to Cart button for each Individual item, also for each item the  Individual price must be listed. I have seen the following can be done but i need to get it working in a grouped product;

[Adding Woocommerce Add to Cart Button to related products and product listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036157/adding-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-to-related-products-and-product-listing)

Any suggestions? Many Thanks!

Comment: if you show me the code to that works with all products I will show you how to make it work with grouped products only.

Comment: This is perfect!!! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres how to make a hook work with grouped products in woocommerce. Just replace the add_action() below with any add_action or remove_action you want to use.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woo_custom_hook_function');

function woo_cusom_hook_function() {

    global $post;

    if (function_exists( 'get_product' )) {
        $product = get_product( $post->ID );

        if ($product->is_type( 'grouped' )) {
        // anything you hook into above will be run here for grouped products only.
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also help me how to add the image for each product? I now have the grouped product image but not the loose images pro product. Many thanks in advanced

Comment: I found the following, but i ma not sure where to add the code...     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524550/woocommerce-grouped-product-images

Comment: Please up vote and mark as answer if this solved your problem, i'd suggest opening a new question and providing more information about your next problem.

Comment: Hi mate! Nevermind i found it!! :) ill vote for sure!