# Woocommerce 3 - Individual Add to Cart Button for Grouped Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a grouped product and on the page there is a table with the individual products. For adding them to the cart you have to select the quantity or use the checkbox (if "sold individually" is selected). The add to cart button is displayed below the table.

**I am trying to do the following:**

Instead of showing the quantity field or the checkbox i would like to have an individual add to chart button for every individual product in the table.

I have found this question, but it does not work for me: [Woocommerce Grouped Products with Individual “Add To Cart” Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123009/woocommerce-grouped-products-with-individual-add-to-cart-button)

Does anyone has an idea how to do this? Many thanks!